# Toggle Class on Top Level Containing Division Using Data Attribute on Link

Tags: javascript

As the title of this thread suggests, I'm trying to toggle a class on a div using data attributes on the link.

I've added my basic html and js.  I've gotten it to toggle the class, but I need it to toggle a different class depending on which link is hovered.

I've added my HTML and javascript below. If anyone can help me fill in the blanks, I would be extremely grateful.

```
    var switchData = $("[data-switch]");
    var breakoutClass = switchData.attr('data-switch');
    $('.js-breakout-switch').hover(function() {
        $(this).parents('.js-product-breakout').toggleClass('show-' + breakoutClass);
    });
```

```
<div class="product-breakout js-product-breakout">
    <section class="breakout-item">
        <p class="breakout-item-text"><a class="breakout-item-link color-white js-breakout-switch" data-switch="01" href="">View Part</a></p>
    </section>
    <section class="breakout-item">
        <p class="breakout-item-text"><a class="breakout-item-link color-white js-breakout-switch" data-switch="02" href="">View Part</a></p>
    </section>
    <section class="breakout-item">
        <p class="breakout-item-text"><a class="breakout-item-link color-white js-breakout-switch" data-switch="03" href="">View Part</a></p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but I think you need to declare your variables inside of your hover function, or at least update them inside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the value of the `data-switch` attribute using $(this).data('switch'), which corresponds to the class you want to toggle.

```
$(".js-breakout-switch").hover(function () {
  const breakoutClass = $(this).data('switch');
  $(this)
    .parents(".js-product-breakout")
    .toggleClass(breakoutClass ? `show-${breakoutClass}` : '');
});
```

Below is the full example code:

```js
$(".js-breakout-switch").hover(function () {
  const breakoutClass = $(this).data('switch');
  $(this)
    .parents(".js-product-breakout")
    .toggleClass(breakoutClass ? `show-${breakoutClass}` : '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-breakout js-product-breakout">
    <section class="breakout-item">
        <p class="breakout-item-text"><a class="breakout-item-link color-white js-breakout-switch" data-switch="01" href="">View Part</a></p>
    </section>
    <section class="breakout-item">
        <p class="breakout-item-text"><a class="breakout-item-link color-white js-breakout-switch" data-switch="02" href="">View Part</a></p>
    </section>
    <section class="breakout-item">
        <p class="breakout-item-text"><a class="breakout-item-link color-white js-breakout-switch" data-switch="03" href="">View Part</a></p>
    </section>
</div>
```